# Issue in setting header view for RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am facing problem in setting the header for my `RecyclerView`. I have used the following code in my `RecyclerView` adapter for setting the header view, but it is showing only the header view in my list, and not inflating the list_item layout.

Here is my code :

```
package com.example.samarthkejriwal.easyroads;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.samarthkejriwal.easyroads.Rv_adapter.MyViewHolder;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by samarthkejriwal on 10/08/17.
 */

public class Rv_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<PlacesResponse.CustomA> stLstStores;
    private ArrayList<Modal> models;

    private static final int TYPE_HEAD=0;
    private static final int TYPE_LIST=1;

    public Rv_adapter(ArrayList<PlacesResponse.CustomA> stores, ArrayList<Modal> storeModels) {

        stLstStores = stores;
        models = storeModels;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


        if(viewType==TYPE_LIST) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_listitem, parent, false);

            return new MyViewHolder(itemView,viewType);
        }
        else if(viewType==TYPE_HEAD)
        {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_header, parent, false);

            return new MyViewHolder(itemView,viewType);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position)
    {

        Log.i("adapter_posn",holder.getAdapterPosition()+"");

        Log.i("view type",holder.view_type+"");
            if(holder.view_type == TYPE_LIST) {

                holder.res_name.setText(stLstStores.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()-1).name);
//                holder.res_address.setText(models.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).address);
//                holder.res_phone.setText(models.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).phone_no);
//                holder.res_rating.setText(String.valueOf(models.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).rating));
//                holder.res_distance.setText(String.valueOf(models.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).distance));
            }
            else if (holder.view_type == TYPE_HEAD)
            {
//                holder.current_location.setText(String.valueOf(models.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).current_location));
            }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.i("count: ",stLstStores.size()+"");
        Log.i("count1",models.size()+"");
        return  stLstStores.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView res_name;
        TextView res_rating;
        TextView res_address;
        TextView res_phone;
        TextView res_distance;
        TextView current_location;
        int view_type;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView,int viewType) {
            super(itemView);

            if(viewType == TYPE_LIST) {

                view_type=1;
                this.res_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                this.res_rating = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
                this.res_address = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.address);
                this.res_phone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.phone);
                this.res_distance = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.distance);
            }
          else  if(viewType == TYPE_HEAD){
                view_type = 0;
                this.current_location = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.location_tv);

            }
        }


    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot for the `RecyclerView`:

[image]

**In the screenshot only the header view is being shown through the whole RecyclerView**

Comment: make sure value of viewType should be changed after Header inflated.

Answer (score 1):

add this to method

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if(position==0){
        return TYPE_HEAD;
    } else {
        return TYPE_LIST;
    } 
}
```

instead of `view_type` used in function

Comment: yes its working now. A small mistake and now its done , Thanks :)